# TMDB API Is Showing The Same Data In ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, clone

## My Problem

I'm trying to make this Netflix Clone by a YouTube called [Clever Programmer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtMThy8QKqU&t). I'm trying to use an API called [TMDB](https://www.themoviedb.org/?language=en-US) to display movies. However, whenever I try to display the movies the data seems to be the same. I'm not getting any error messages except for one that's in the console.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

### The top of the page (which is normal)

[image: Top of the page]

### Bottom of the page (where my problem is)

[image: My problem]

I've tried refreshing the page and restarting the app but I got the same results.

## Code

### App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import Row from "./Row";
import requests from "./requests";
import Banner from "./Banner";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* Nav */}
      <Banner></Banner>
      <Row
        title="NETFLIX ORIGINALS"
        fetchUrl={requests.fetchNetflixOriginals}
        isLargeRow={true}
      />
      <Row title="Trending Now" fetchUrl={requests.fetchTrending} />
      <Row title="Top Rated" fetchUrl={requests.fetchTopRated} />
      <Row title="Action Movies" fetchUrl={requests.fetchTopActionMovies} />
      <Row title="Comedy Movies" fetchUrl={requests.fetchTopComedyMovies} />
      <Row title="Horror Movies" fetchUrl={requests.fetchTopHorrorMovies} />
      <Row title="Romance Movies" fetchUrl={requests.fetchTopRomanceMovies} />
      <Row title="Documentarires" fetchUrl={requests.fetchTopDocumentaries} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

### Banner.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "./axois";
import requests from "./requests";

function Banner() {
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const request = await axios.get(requests.fetchNetflixOriginals);
      setMovie(
        request.data.results[
          Math.floor(Math.random() * request.data.results.length - 1)
        ]
      );
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  console.log(movie);

  return (
    <header
      className="banner"
      style={{
        backgroundSize: "cover",
        backgroundImage: `url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${movie?.backdrop_path})`,
        backgroundPosition: "center center",
      }}
    >
      <div className="banner_contents">
        {/* title */}
        <h1>{movie?.title || movie?.name || movie?.original_name}</h1>
        {/* div > 2 buttons */}
        {/* description */}
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Banner;
```

### Row.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "./axois";
import "./Row.css";

const base_url = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/";

function Row({ title, fetchUrl, isLargeRow }) {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

  // A snipet of caode which runs based on a specific condition/variable
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl);
      setMovies(request.data.results);
      return request;
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchUrl]);

  return (
    <div className="row">
      {/* title */}
      <h2>{title}</h2>

      <div className="row_posters">
        {/* serveral row_poster(s) */}

        {movies.map((movie) => (
          <img
            key={movie.id}
            className={`row_poster ${isLargeRow && "row_posterLarge"}`}
            src={`${base_url}${
              isLargeRow ? movie.poster_path : movie.backdrop_path
            }`}
            alt={movie.name}
          />
        ))}
      </div>

      {/* container -> posters */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Row;
```

### Requests.js

```
const APIKEY = "not sure how confidential an API key is";

const requests = {
  fetchTrending: `/trending/all/week?api_key=${APIKEY}&language=en-US`,
  fetchNetflixOriginals: `/discover/tv?api_key=${APIKEY}&with_networks=213`,
  fetchTopRated: `/movie/top_rated?api_key=${APIKEY}&language=en-US`,
  fetchTopActionMovies: `/discover/movie?api_key=${APIKEY}&with_geners=28`,
  fetchTopComedyMovies: `/discover/movie?api_key=${APIKEY}&with_geners=35`,
  fetchTopHorrorMovies: `/discover/movie?api_key=${APIKEY}&with_geners=27`,
  fetchTopRomanceMovies: `/discover/movie?api_key=${APIKEY}&with_geners=10749`,
  fetchTopDocumentaries: `/discover/movie?api_key=${APIKEY}&with_geners=99`,
};

export default requests;
```

### Axios.js

```
import axios from "axios";

// base url to make requests to the movie database
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/",
});

export default instance;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your endpoints are wrong.

```
fetchTopHorrorMovies: `/discover/movie?api_key=${APIKEY}&with_geners=27`,
```

They should be with_genres.

Comment: Ohhhhhh I see it now. Thanks for the answer it worked oerfectly.